# How to retrieve data entered in content control in webaddin

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have a richtext content control named `firstname` in a Word document. I am trying to access its content but am not able retrieve it.

This is a sample method given in msdn. Using it I am able to get the control's id and its type but not the data. Please let me know whether any way to access the same?

```
function bindContentControl() {
  Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(
   'FirstName', Office.BindingType.Text, {id:'firstName'}, 

   function (result) { 
     if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) { 
      write('Control bound. Binding.id: ' + result.value.id + ' Binding.type: ' + result.value.type); } 
     else { 
       write('Error:', result.error.message); 
     } 
   });
 } 

  // Function that writes to a div with id='message' on the page. 
Funktion write(message){ 
  document.getElementById('message').innerText += message; }
```

Comment: Which version of Word are you targeting?

Comment: Using word api 1.3 n supported version

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you provided creates a binding to an object with the name 'FirstName'.

You will want to use context.document.contentControls.getByTitle() to retrieve the content control of a given name.  Here's my sample code.

```
  await Word.run(async (context) => {

    let controls = context.document.contentControls.getByTitle("FirstName");

    controls.load();
    await context.sync();

    //assuming there's only one para.  
    controls.items[0].paragraphs.load();
    await context.sync();


    console.log(controls.items[0].paragraphs.items[0].text);
  });
```